# External Object Sync Without Wiping Cusomizations?

Tags: custom-object, lightning-connect, sync, externalobjects

I have a table in a PostgreSQL database that I am exposing as an External ODATA Object to bring into my Salesforce Org. There are about 25 columns on this table.

Within my Org, in the external object settings, I have updated all of the field labels as necessary.

Now, I added a new column to the PostgreSQL table that I also need to bring into my org.

Since I added the field, I would now have to “Validate and Sync” the external object again. However, this is going to erase all of my field labels / meta ..

Is there a better way to approach this where it’s not destructive to the customizations made? I can’t imagine that people don’t want to change or add a column down the road.

Do we really have to resync the meta from scratch and start over for such a simple change?

Answer (score 1):

I know its not great, but you could export the metadata for that external object as it is now, and then re-deploy it back and it will put the labels back to the way it was.